# Any way to find out who are the top meta.site.SE users?

Tags: support, users, per-site-meta

As we all know ([blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/new-per-site-metas/), [explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64267/is-there-a-reason-why-we-gain-ghost-reputation-on-the-meta-of-se-website/64268#64268)), Stack Exchange 2.0 Meta sites "inherit" reptuation from the main site, which works out great for privileges, community transferability, free down-votes, etc.

We also know that users on Meta gain "ghost" reputation, which really only comes into play on badges and on the user's profile "Reputation" tab.

**Is there any way to view lists of the top Meta users?**  I believe this would be useful to find historically helpful answers as Meta SE sites grow to significant sizes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per site metas now have this Participation tab on the Users page which shows the top/most involved users of the site. The rankings on this (according to the tooltip on the tab) are worked out via:

> Users most active on this site in the last 60 days (combined number of posts, votes, comments and edits).

Comment: Great feature, thanks! I noticed this a couple months ago when Workplace opened, but had totally forgotten about this old question.

Answer (score 9):

<sup>*I asked this question because I'd like to know if there is any way this is (or could be) built into the site. However...*</sup>

The **[Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com)** can be used to analyze users/questions/answers since it has access to the per-site Metas.

So, I put together [Top users by calculated rep](https://data.stackexchange.com/programmersmeta/s/1334/top-users-by-calculated-rep)
 to give a rough calculated rep for this purpose:

**[Programmers Meta](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com)**:
[image]

Comment: Oh, phooey. I was just about to suggest Data Explorer for calculating what the assumed reputation would be. Well, guess you already know about it, so it puts a bit of meat into your request.

Comment: @Grace Note - sorry, I didn't mean to be disingenuous in my question at all.  I just didn't want to include an answer in the question either...

Comment: @Renesis: It's okay, this is proper -- there was no way to tell this was going to be an immediate-self-answer-question. :)

Comment: This is incorrect.  I am not top user everywhere.  Please fix.

Comment: What @Jon said, Renesis. This was entirely proper and I wouldn't have called that disingenuous. Otherwise, I'd've had stronger words than "phooey", I imagine. ♪

Comment: What you could've done is left a comment saying "I'm about to self-answer this with a SEDE query." But yeah, no big.